# How to remove border from appearing around the image?

Tags: css

I'm not sure if this is even a border, but I'm trying so hard to find out why is this appearing around the image when I use CSS Sprites on the middle image?

[image]

I did tried to set border = 0

```
#twitter-big {background-position: -0px -503px; width:32px; height:32px; border:0px;}


<a href='http://twitter.com/TwitterID; ?>'><img class="sprites1" id="twitter-big"/></a>
```

can this somehow coming from the `a` tag? or what it is really and how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called outline rather than border. You can set the anchor's outline property to none to remove it.

[Resource](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp)

Comment: As you mentioned yourself, it results from the behavior of the anchor tag. You should set outline:none for <a>, not for <img />

Comment: Did you check the resource link? It depends on the browser you use. Especially, IE needs a DOCTYPE declaration to take outline value into consideration. Mozilla Firefox or Webkit browsers should not ignore outline

Comment: I did I'm using all the browsers I installed on my PC,

Comment: Works for me in Mozilla and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks I will try see what can I do.